# Sending JS variable data to a downloadable page

Tags: php, javascript

This javascript function takes JSON and formats it to XML.  The data is a long XML string, whic I would like to allow the user to download. I'm trying to use ajax to post the data to a php page wichi will create the file and then allow the user to download it.

```
 json2xml(eval(data));
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'download/functions.php',
   data: xml2,
   dataType: XML
 });
```

I have used this PHP function to write to a file, but I'm not sure how to now send the js variable to this function.

```
 $data = $_POST['xml2'];

 writetoxml($data, 'WF-XML'.$current. '.xml'); 

 function writetoxml($stringData, $myFile) {
    $current = date('m-d-Y-g-i-s');
    $fh = fopen('download/'.$myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    download($file);
  }

 function downloadFile($file) {

 if(!file)
 {
     // File doesn't exist, output error
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
     // Set headers
     header("Cache-Control: public");
     header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
     header("Content-Type: application/csv");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

     // Read the file from disk
     readfile($file);
     exit;
 }
```

}

This is currently returning a server 500 error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Isn't this a forum for helping people when they're stuck with a problem?

Comment: @user1413248 What is the structure of the data in your xml2 variable?  Also, a clarification on your goal might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated:

With your provided jQuery AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'download/yourphpscript.php',
   data: { xml: xml2 },
   dataType: XML
});
```

Your PHP would look like this:

```
<?php
$xml = $_POST['xml'];
// Not sure where you're trying to get $file from

writetoxml($xml, $file);

function writetoxml($stringData, $myFile) {
    $current = date('m-d-Y-g-i-s');
    $fh = fopen('download/'.$myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $stringdata);
    fclose($fh);

    download($file);
}

function download($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Try passing an object  (in this case `{ key: value }` into the data property of the `$.ajax` call so that you can reference it by your key.  In this case our key is `xml` so on the PHP side, we grab `$_POST['xml']` and that should give you the contents of xml2.

The download code was taken from the [PHP docs on readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).  However, I still can't help but think there is a better way to accomplish this.

I would **HIGHLY** recommend against allowing the user to effectively create a web accessible file containing whatever they want on your server.  As aforementioned, a clarification of your general goal would be helpful.  I think I understand *what* you're trying to do but *why* you are doing it would be nice to know as there may be a better and safer way to accomplish the same result.

Comment: XML2 is a JSON string which was formatted into XML format.  I would like the user of the page to be able to download a file with the XML formatted data in it. XML2 is already the format that it needs to be, I just need to put that data into a file which can be downloaded.  Sorry, is that more clear?

Comment: @user1413248 That is a little clearer.  
the url: attribute is telling the browser where to send the XHR request so setting it to the name of the file you want to download will not work.  you have to set that property to the URL of the php script that grabs the data and returns a download.


You may want to look into this question http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/01/how-to-download-data-as-a-file-from-javascript.html.  That may be a better way since you already have the data in the format you are wanting.

Comment: Thank you for explaining for process.  The method that's mentioned on that page won't work for me because this application will be reused a lot and each file needs to have a unique name.

Comment: My data is a long XML string.  How do I retrieve it in the PHP after it has been posted?

Comment: I've added more info to the top.  Any way you can help me resolve this issue?

Comment: @user1413248 Well they closed your question haha.  Lemme double check something and I'll update my answer.  I'm pretty sure I can still do that.  First things first, check your /var/log/apache2/error.log file for errors or use the network tab in Chrome's developer tools to see if the response sheds any light on the error the server is having (500 is internal error).

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code with some thing to try.  However, your best bet now is to debug the 500 error by way of your apache error logs and chrome's dev tools.  If you are using a shared web host, you may have to check your logs in a different location than `/var/log/`.